# Why my route doesn't work upon adding a middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I wrote the route shown below in my routes:

```
Route::post('check_user', ['middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthControllerGeneral@checkUser']);
```

this route upon hitting from postman with method `POST` returns a `NotFoundHttpException`. However, If I remove the middleware it works. This route is under a group prefix `api/v1_0` and hence I hit `http://localhost:8000/api/v1_0/check_user` with `POST`.

Please shed some light on this issue. I already tried clearing route cache.

Answer (score 0):

try running `composer dump-autoload` from your project root in terminal

you could also add the following

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: nah, doesn't change anything

Comment: the route is listed clearly when i run `php artisan route:list` but I don't understand why it goes to NotFoundException

Comment: have you disabled csrf protection?

Comment: Yes.. For now, as I'm still developing

Comment: can you also share your middleware `handle()` method?

Comment: That is from jwt tymon library.. Nothing additional added.. Strange thing is my other routes work properly.. With the same middleware

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `checkUser` method onto some other Controller and it started working.
I'm still not sure why it didn't work in my `AuthControllerGeneral`. The only difference between the two controllers are the traits that come along with AuthController of laravel which are present in the former and absent in the latter.

It would be nice if some one could explain the resons for this.